# Vlookup Function Multiple Spreadsheets with Concatenation

Tags: vba, vlookup

Help, I can't seem to get this vlookup to work.  Attempting to consolidate multiple spreadsheets into a third Spreadsheet.  I use concatenated columns in each worksheet as the reference and target ranges and then populate the values on a third worksheet that has all column headings of the first two.  the concatenation works perfectly and the population of data in each cell on the third worksheet is correct as I tested this with a random character but the vlookup keeps failing 1004 Error and when I stick in On Error Resume Next,  I get nothing. Have spend 10 hours trying to figure this out so any help will be greatly appreciated.

'Next prepare the data in each worksheet (MyT&E & MyShop) for comparison
'Use Report Number/Invoice ID,Reimbursement Amount/Amount,Reimbursement Currency/Currency, GL Account/Account

```
Dim theRange As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Lastcol As Long
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Firstcol As Long

Sheets("MYSHOP").Select
LastrowMYSHOP = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
LastColMYSHOP = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
theRange = ("A3:" & "A" & LastrowMYSHOP)

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Concatenate"
Range("A3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(right(RC8,7),RC6,RC12,RC11)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(theRange)
Range(theRange).Select
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Sheets("MYTE").Select
LastrowMYTE = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
LastcolMYTE = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
theRange = ("A2:" & "A" & LastrowMYTE)

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Concatenate"
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC5,RC15,RC18,RC19)"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(theRange)
Range(theRange).Select
Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

'Next perform the lookup

```
Sheets("Consolidate").Select
Firstrow = 6
Firstcol = 26
LastrowConsolidate = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
LastcolConsolidate = Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column

Dim ws1, ws2, ws3 As Worksheet
Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim RefRange As Range

Set ws1 = Sheets("MYTE")
Set ws2 = Sheets("MYSHOP")
Set ws3 = Sheets("Consolidate")

Set RefRange = ws1.Range("A2:" & "A" & LastrowMYTE)
Set TargetRange = ws2.Range("A3:" & "AD" & LastrowMYSHOP)

    On Error Resume Next
    LastColMYSHOP = LastColMYSHOP + 1 'Allow for the additional concatenation column
    For i = 2 To LastColMYSHOP
        For Each cl In RefRange
            Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, TargetRange, i, False)
            ws3.Cells(Firstrow, Firstcol).Value = Result
            Firstrow = Firstrow + 1
        Next cl
        Firstrow = 6
        Firstcol = Firstcol + 1
    Next i
```